# $.ajax ignoring data param for DELETE requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters, jquery

I just updated from jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.4.3, and I'm seeing some new behavior when making AJAX DELETE requests.  For some reason, the data being passed in my `data` parameter is not being sent to the server.  For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/example',
    data: {id: 12},
    type: 'DELETE'
});
```

Ends up sending a DELETE request to `/example` with no additional data.  However, this type of call passes the parameters just fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/example?id=12',
    type: 'DELETE'
});
```

Has anyone else seen similar behavior?  Is there a reason this is no longer working (i.e.: is it by design, or is it a bug)?  Any suggestions on how to get it working?

Also, in case anyone is wondering why I don't simply want to pass the parameters as part of the URL string, it's because I'm ultimately attempting to use the `$.ajaxSetup` callback, providing some general parameters there (namely the `authenticity_token` parameter used to protect against forgery in Rails).  This all worked fine prior to trying jQuery 1.4.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery [will only append parameters to the querystring for `GET` requests only](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L279) (and [no body for `DELETE` requests](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L7)), so this is intentional behavior in jQuery 1.4.3.

However, there is a change since then ([commit here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/09022e0b09db71259751e7146bb64727615028af)) to allow a body for `DELETE` requests in the 1.4.4 release.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  Any suggestions on a workaround?  Given your response, I attempted to update `settings.url` in the `$.ajaxSend()` callback such that I append the query string values there for DELETE requests; however, it looks like the returned value of `settings.url` isn't being captured for use in jQuery 1.4.3 as it is in 1.3.2.  Any other thoughts on dealing with this, other than manually appending the same parameter to every single request everywhere in my code?

Comment: @Matt - I think 1.4.4 is due out very soon as a bugfix release, look at this commit an hour ago labeling it 1.4.4pre: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/9b97599fa4d615a91d1605d9c664c50f576911ce I would say hang tight a few days, grab 1.4.4 final and you're all set.  Here's a blog post on it: http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/24/community-updates-2610/

Comment: Unfortunately deadlines force me to deal with this now.  I guess I'll update the calls inline for now, and refactor in a couple days when this becomes available.  Thanks so much for your insight, you're always incredibly helpful on here!

Comment: The answer is a little outdated. jQuery appends parameters to `GET` and `HEAD`, and for `DELETE` it gives you freedom how to deal with it. For more details see my response.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be related to the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) parameter? It usually relates to complex types and not a simple id parameter but worth checking if this is not the case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/example',
    data: { id: someValue },
    traditional: true,
    type: 'DELETE'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't assume how to deal with content for `DELETE` request. The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) also doesn't specify this.

There were few issues about it. There were attempts  to implement behaviour as in other web tools - to treat `DELETE` content as a query part of URI.
**The final statement is that developer decide what to do with DELETE content**. jQuery provides sufficient tools for that. 
For more check discussion in [$.ajax DELETE request not passing data parameters](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11586) issue.

About other methods, jQuery adds a request content to `GET` and `HEAD`. Check `rnoContent` variable in jQuery source.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**jQuery**

```
$("#DeleUser").click(function () {
    $.ajax({ type: "DELETE", url: userController + "DeleteUser/" + $("#UserId").val() + "?UserPhoto=" + $("#UserPhoto").val() })
    .done(function (data) {
        $('#MsgUser').text("User deleted");
        $("#User").trigger("reset");
    })
    .fail(function (response, status, error) {
        $('#MsgUser').text(error);
    });
});
```

**WebAPI Controller/Action**

```
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            string userPhoto = request.QueryString["UserPhoto"];
            Users user = new Users();
            user.UserId = id;
            user.Delete(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBName"].ConnectionString, id);
            if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotosPath"]) + userPhoto))
            File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhotosPath"]) + userPhoto);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = "Exception: " + e.Message;
            throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```