# How to get DELETE request parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is how I want to delete a record using jquery ajax

```
deleteFile: function(obj) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'delete',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'service/lead.php?a=deleteFile',
            data: {id: $(obj).attr('data-lf-id')}
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log("done");
        }).fail(function(error) {

        });
    }
```

This works but how am I suppsed to get the `id` value on the `lead.php` page? This is what I am currently doing but it doesn't capture the `id` value.

```
//service/lead.php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "DELETE") {
    if ($_GET['a'] == 'deleteFile') {
        echo json_encode($lead->deleteLeadFile($_REQUEST['id']));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET)` show?

Comment: It only shows this `[a] => deleteFile`

Comment: what does `$(obj).attr('data-lf-id')` show? Also, what does `print_r($_REQUEST)` show?

Comment: What does print_r($_REQUEST) show?

Comment: Thats is the id I want to match in the database and then delete that record. I see in that value is sent to the `lead.php` page.

Comment: Since it isn't a GET request, it should be getting sent as a param string to the request body. Open your debugging console and inspect the request headers being sent.

Comment: @KevinB, yes I see it in the devtool form data `id` is sent to the `lead.php`

Comment: form data... did you try looking at $_POST? I wouldn't have expected it to be there, but if it's sending it as form data, might as well try.

Comment: `$_POST` is empty and `$_REQUEST` is same as `$_GET` which only shows `[a] => deleteFile`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data in the ajax DELETE request other than headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088955/how-to-pass-data-in-the-ajax-delete-request-other-than-headers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535340/is-it-possible-to-append-request-parameters-to-a-http-delete-request-in-ajax

Comment: A `DELETE` HTTP request is telling your web server you want to delete the file `service/lead.php`. It has nothing to do with what you are planning.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your Ajax type to either 'POST' or 'GET".  You can then use the appropriate $_GET or $_POST variable to retrieve your id.

```
deleteFile: function(obj) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'service/lead.php?a=deleteFile',
            data: {id: $(obj).attr('data-lf-id')}
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log("done");
        }).fail(function(error) {

        });
    }

//service/lead.php

if ($_GET['a'] == 'deleteFile') {
    echo json_encode($lead->deleteLeadFile($_POST['id']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_get_contents(“php://input”)
```

This always gives you raw request data - you have to parse it [with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) if you send urlencoded data, with `json_decode` if you send JSON].

But you should keep it RESTful and not RPC-like, and issue a delete over `/resource/:id`.